# How to set up initial test data in database Java project? (possibly not using raw SQL statements)

Tags: java, database, automated-tests

I’m creating new automated tests java project. This will be mainly selenium test (selenide) + API test (Rest assured).

I would like to integrate those tests with application DB.
By integrate I mean:
I can setup initial application state in every test in “Given” context.

For a background, previously I made C# test project using: https://bitbucket.org/mk_meros/databag/wiki/Home this allowed me to make classes each represent different tables. Then I could use it in Given step implementation to insert data directly to DB and create initial test data. Each tests had ONE common  initial app state  + possibly his own Given Exists custom data, after test end data was cleared from DB, and another test was creating his own initial setup.

Can I find something similar to use in Java project?

Limitation od databag is only integration with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/), which should be an answer to your problem.